# node module in Electron

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

Need help on getting babyparse module working in Electron, after `npm install babyparse` module and still getting `Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'babyparse'`.

```
var Baby = require("babyparse");
window.$ = window.jQuery = require('./jquery.min.js');
var csv;
function readyFn(d){

parsed = Baby.parse(csv);

Papa.parse(data, {
    complete: function(results) {
        console.log("Finished:", results.data);
    }
});
}
$(document).ready(readyFn);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to re-bind `require` to `window` before using it.

In your index.html file (loaded my Electron), before loading your js, add `window.nRequire = require`. Then call `var Baby = nRequire("babyparse");` anywhere in your app.

Answer (score 0):

You could try following:

1. check if the module is inside your node_modules folder of your electron app.
2. If it is not install it via `npm install babyparse --save` be sure that you have the "--save" at the end, to install it inside your app and not global.
3. If it is allready inside your node_modules folder, maybe something went wrong, when you installed it. So uninstall it `npm uninstall babyparse --save` and install it again. Or better you could also run a complete npm install inside your electron folder for updating all your modules.

Answer (score 0):

- Remove your node_modules folder
- `npm cache clean`
- `npm install`