# Node Modules Not Being Found in Electron App

Tags: node.js, electron

I am in progress of making a simple Electron app. When I boot the app from the console on my Win10 PC (using the classic `npm i && npm start`), it boots the modules and works like a charm. When I bring it to an iMac running High Sierra for testing for its deployment, it crashes when I try to use the app with the error of `Cannot find module {insert module here}`. I've tried clearing the cache (recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33856012/node-module-in-electron)), but it has been to no avail. I have my `package.json`, `index.js`, and `downloader.js` all linked below for ease.

**Edit:** Sorry for not linking before! The repo is [here](https://github.com/Incrested/YouTubeDownload) (it's pretty easy to find the `package.json` and `index.js`, the `downloader.js` is in the `js/`)

I'm open to any and all help! Thanks in advance for, like I said, any and all help!

Comment: can you check that you're running the latest version of node and npm on the iMac?

Comment: Last time I checked: if you compiled the Electron app into a .app, .exe, etc., you don't need Node/NPM. I'll try installing it and if it helps I'll make an announcement either way.

Comment: oh, sorry I thought you had cloned down the repo and was trying to get a dev environment working on your iMac xD my bad sorry. (just ignore my previous comment)

Comment: It's fine mate: I'm waiting for the a-ok from the place we're deploying to to start installing Node on the macs; any other ideas for the time being?

Comment: can you try disabling any antivirus software you have running? It might be blocking it from installing

Comment: Anti-Virus is a myth among Macs. In other words, we don't have anything regarding anti-virus on the Macs.